# Batch Files: -actions parameter - Is it a valid param?

Tags: batch-file

I am running a batch file containing the following:

```
C:\Utilities\FDD_TEST\FDD.exe -actions=C:\Utilities\FDD_TEST\FDDBatch.cfg
```

But it fails to run.

Is the -actions parameter a valid parameter? If so, what could likely be the cause why that batch file does not run?

Thanks

Comment: Whether `-actions` is valid or not depends on the program this batch file is trying to run. What is this `FDD.exe` ?

Comment: it is an application that compiles a bunch of files into a single file

Comment: Sure, but can you link the website of this tool ? And have you checked in its documentation if it accepts the parameter `-actions` ?

Comment: it is a custom application. and it is not hosted anywhere.It also do not have any documentation.So you are saying that the -actions param is a custom one as well, and not a standard batch command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, the part `-action=...` is not interpreted by Batch, and it only depends on your program `FDD.exe`.

In Batch, when you call

```
C:\Path\To\My\Exe.exe /option1 -option 2 arg1 ...
```

All the content following the .exe path is given directly to the called program. On my example, `Exe.exe` will receive as arguments `/option1 -option2 arg1 ...`, and it's up to it to use it or not, and how to use it. It none of Batch concern.

Then, you should check this `FDD.exe` program, to find out what is the syntax it expects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what I wanted to know.